# How do specify double subscript

Tags: math-mode, subscripts

For example I need to specify a term x subscript a subscript b. 
For a x subscript a, I can write it as x_{a}. However, x_{a}_{b} is not supported. How do I do that?

Comment: Maybe `x_{a_b}` or `{x_a}_b` (even this last is strange)?

Comment: the first one works well. If you post this as an answer, I would accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to insert more than one character as index, you have to put it inside braces. This rule is for the index as well, I mean, if index has more than one char, use braces again.

```
$x_{a_b}$ and $x_{a_{bc}}$ (or ${x_a}_b = {x_a}_p$)
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: @Mico, I wrote that in the comments... and the output looks strange.

Comment: I suppose that `x_{a_b}` means "the variable `x`, indexed by `a_b`", whereas `{x_a}_b` means "the variable `x_a`, indexed by `b`". In the former case, `b` is rendered in script-script style, while in the latter it is rendered in script style (and `a` is rendered in "cramped" script style).

Comment: @Mico, yes. I also think that. But looks ugly, in my opinion... lol